# 1970s sci-fi book. Main character has a mind-control implant called a Bofron(?) and can transport self to other planets

Tags: story-identification, dystopia, mind-control

Book I am looking for may be YA sci-fi book but I can’t recall. I think the protagonist in the story was named Ben..not 100% though. He was part of a society that used some kind of mind control and he had some kind of implant called a Bofron that I think that they could kill him with. He rejected society as it was and had some power to transport himself and his lady friend to another planet, and would come and go between worlds.